# Directory permission changes failing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, permissions, ubuntu-12.04

I've tried to change permissions on a directory to 775. I've used this command:

```
sudo chmod -v 775 /vagrant/app/cache
```

It tells me that the command executed successfully:

```
mode of `/vagrant/app/cache' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
```

however, when I then run:

```
ls -l /vagrant/app
```

the cache directory is listed as:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   136 Mar  5 12:03 cache
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I should do to fix it?!

UPDATE:
This is the output from

```
df -T
```

I think it shows that the filesystem is vboxsf. I'm using VirtualBox...

```
Filesystem                 Type     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/precise64-root ext4      82711212   2904248  75664680   4% /
udev                       devtmpfs    178072         4    178068   1% /dev
tmpfs                      tmpfs        74852       284     74568   1% /run
none                       tmpfs         5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                       tmpfs       187128         0    187128   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                  ext2        233191     24966    195784  12% /boot
/srv                       vboxsf   117649480 106406988  11242492  91% /srv
/vagrant                   vboxsf   117649480 106406988  11242492  91% /vagrant
```

Comment: What file system are you using? There is a bug report on debian which might be the cause, but depends on your system. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=296836

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but... I don't know! How can I find out?!

Comment: `df -T` will give you the filesystem. Once you have this have a look at the above link and see if it could be your problem.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the output from that command. I don't think the bug report is relevant to my filesystem.

Comment: I agree. Seems your problem lies elsewhere. Let me do some digging and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/

You can set mount options in the vagrantfile and since the vagrant directory is a shared directory that allows you to set permissions properly.